# Introduction to Python - Help me understand simple execution

Tags: python

```
>>> def double(x):
        x += x
>>> a=[1,2,3,4]
>>> b=a
>>> double(b)
>>> print(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> print(b)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Could someone help me understand how the a list got doubled in this process? I understand how b's list doubled but not a

Thank you!

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Your code is impossible to understand run together in one line. It looks like the doubling occurs simply because of `x += x`, that is, "add the list to itself."

Comment: Incidentally, be careful: `b=a` means b and a are **the same list**. If you add to one, you will add to the other!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your code looks like:

```
def double(x):
    x += x

a=[1,2,3,4]
b=a
double(b)
print(a)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
[1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4]
```

And the reason is simply that if you have a list `x = [1,2,3]` and a list `y = [6,7,8]`, then `x + y` gives you `[1,2,3,6,7,8]`. So the line `x += x` adds the elements of `x` to the end of itself, doubling it.

The reason that `a` doubles when `b` doubles is because python lists are *mutable*. You can find out more here: https://codehabitude.com/2013/12/24/python-objects-mutable-vs-immutable/